# Local Sensitive Hashing using a arbitray non euclidean metric

Tags: data-structures, nearest-neighbor, approximation

I have a very specific question. I work on a project, were I need to find nearest neighbours (k and near).
As I dont need the excat ones and want to be able to extend to high dimensions, I  focused on LSH.

My data has a distance that is a metric, but non euclidean. I found many ways for vector space with euclidean metric (e.g. the p stable distribution), binary coding(via projections) or string based.

What I am searching are papers that present a LSH template for an arbitrary metric. Does anyone has some refernece to papers?

Thanks in advance 
Dan

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is quite new:
I think this paper may help
http://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/aaai/aaai10/paper/download/1839/2032

It suggests strategies for non-metric data,
which is even worse than having a non-euclidean case.

Comment: Kindly quote the most relevant part of the link provided, so that people can find the answer here, even when the link goes down. stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: That paper reads like Greek (don't remember what a Hilbert space is anymore) You mind translating the main points of the algorithm for us?