# Fastest k nearest neighbor with arbitrary metric?

Tags: algorithm, math, discrete-mathematics, nearest-neighbor

The gotcha with this question is "arbitrary metric". If you don't know what that is, it's just the way to measure distance between points. (In the "real" world, the 1-dimensinal distance is just the absolute magnitude of the difference between the two points).

Enough of the pre-lims. I'm trying to find a fast k nearest neighbor algorithm with these properties:

- works on an arbitrary metric
- somewhat easy to implement
- optimized for finding the distance of a set of points to another set of points

Wikipedia gives a list of algorithms and approaches but nothing on implementation.

UPDATE: the metric is the cosine similarity, which does *not* satisfy the triangle inquality. However, it seems that I can use the "angular similarity" (as per Wikipedia).

UPDATE: the use case is natural language processing. "Vectors" are the "context" of a given word, represented by binary properties (ex: the title of the document). So while there may be only a few properties (right now I'm just using 3), each vector has arbitrarily large dimension (in the title example, each title in the database would correspond to a dimension in the vector).

UPDATE: For the curious, I'm implementing this algorithm:

http://josquin.cs.depaul.edu/~mramezani/papers/IEEEIS.pdf

UPDATE: The algorithm will need to find nearest neighbors for about a dozen points from about 100s of points. The average dimension will probably be very large, say 50, (I really don't know yet). And yes, I'm interested in an algorithm, not a library. And yes, estimates are probably good enough.

Comment: I don't think many of these structures are easy to code up with an arbitrary metric. Out of curiosity, does your metric satisfy the triangle inequality?

Comment: What are the properties of this metric? In a general case there no simpler answer.

Comment: @templatetypedef is it possible/meaningful to try k nearest neighbours with a metric that does not satisfy triangle inequality ?

Comment: @igavriil Yep! For any point, you can find the k points nearest to it according to the metric. Those points don't necessarily have to be close to each other, but they can still be the k closest points to our main point.

Comment: Did not know arbitrary metrics made a difference. But yes, it looks like it satisfies the triangle ineq. See the updates

Comment: [Cover tree?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_tree)

Comment: Which is an average size of the pointset? Which is the average dimensions of the pointset? Are you looking for an algorithm or for a library which implements the search? Are you interested in 100% accuracy?

Comment: @G.Samaras see updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advice you to go for Locality-sensitive hashing (LSH), which is in trend right now. It reduces the dimensionality of high-dimensional data, but I am not sure if your dimension will go well with that algorithm. See the Wikipedia [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing) for more.

You can use your own metric, but in general you can do that in many algorithms. Hope this helps.

You could go for RKD trees, a forest of them, but maybe this is too much now.

Comment: It seems that the research paper isn't very practical (go figure)...their way of measuring similar words doesn't scale (because the dim is proportional to total number of docs/links in system!). Gonna check out "string-based" similarity. But will mark this as the answer because, it technically is. Thanks!

Comment: May I ask in which paper are you referring to? :) You are welcome, good question btw, +1.

Comment: "An Intelligent System for Semi-Automatic Evolution of Ontologies" referenced in the question. Was looking at alternative measures of similarity (ex: Most Frequent K Distance) and it seems I'll be using LSH anyway. So double thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the nice question, which made me question myself, you deserved the +1 for sure! Good luck with your project!

Comment: FYI, LSH doesn't really work for arbitrary metrics. There's an algorithm but it's hidden behind arcane math. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17875885/local-sensitive-hashing-using-a-arbitray-non-euclidean-metric. An alternative seems to be to use q-grams + minhashing + LSH

Comment: Good point @UAvalos, thank you very much. For that I am going to give a +1 to an answer of yours I like.